# how to style html escaped data in Vue 2 or 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have user-generated data I'm displaying in a Vue app, so the default Vue behavior of html-escaping the data is perfect.  Except, now I'd like users to be able to search that data, and I'd like to highlight the matching text in the search result.  That means I need my *own* styling to *not* be escaped, even though all the *original* data should still be escaped.

In other words I need to apply my styling *after* the data has been html-escaped, eg:

##### 1. user inputs data:

`some original data that has special characters like > and <`

##### 2. Vue html-escapes this for safe display:

`some original data that has special characters like &gt; and &lt;`

##### 3. dynamically style the search results

Eg if user searched for "original data" it becomes:

`some <span class="my-highlight-style">original data</span> that has special characters like &gt; and &lt;`

Notice how my dynamic styling was *not* html escaped even though the user input was.

I could of course just use `v-html` to bypass the html escape entirely, but then I lose all the safety and benefit of html escaping which I don't want to lose.  Ideally I want to explicitly call Vue's html escape routine, *then* apply my styling so that it does not get escaped, *then* finally render all of that unescaped (since I already applied appropriate escaping programmatically).

Does Vue offer programmatic access to its html escape routine?  (And I'm not talking about `$sanitize` which strips out special characters entirely, I want to preserve them just like normal Vue templating does).   I could of course write my own escape routine, just wondered if I could leverage Vue's instead.

Comment: what do you mean html escaping?  v-html explicitly does not escape your html

Comment: @maembe I would like to have the data fully escaped, so that html elements don't get interpreted and are just displayed literally.  But then I want *my own styling* on top of that to *not* be escaped, so that my styling *does* get interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue uses the Browser's API for encoding HTML content, as mentioned here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html#HTML-content.

So, something like this should offer you the same kind of protection as Vue would from the raw user input. In the computed property, we pass the user data through the `p` element to encode it. Then we chain on top of that our own `highlight` computed property where we can inject our own HTML, and then show that with `v-html`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div><label>Raw text:<br /><textarea v-model="text" cols="50" rows="10" /></label></div>
    <div><label>Search for: <input type="text" v-model="search" /></label></div>
    <p><label>v-html: <span v-html="text" /></label></p>
    <p><label>Highlighted: <span v-html="highlight" /></label></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() { 
    return {
      text: "some original data that has special characters like > and <",
      search: "original data"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    highlight() {
      const html = this.safeHtml;
      return html.replace(this.search, "<span class='my-highlight-style'>$&</span>");
    },
    safeHtml() { 
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.textContent = this.text;
      return p.innerHTML;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.my-highlight-style {
  background: orange;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising!  Am wondering though, will repeatedly calling document.createElement eventually fill up document with junk elements?  My real use case is a SPA that uses this function repeatedly as user interacts with the app.  Should I delete the temp element after using it for html escaping?

Comment: To answer my earlier comment, looks like createElement() does not actually attach to the DOM, so this looks good!  Will try this approach.